# How to do a string match on a set of digits?

Tags: string, lua, match

I have the following data set:

```
Word-1-random
Word-2-random
Word-3-random
Word-4-random
upto
Word-19-random

Other-Word-1-random
Other-Word-2-random
Other-Word-3-random
Other-Word-4-random
upto
Other-Word-19-random
```

Now i want to do a match on a group of date, digits 1 - 5, 6-10, 11-15 etc. 
I thought it was the following:

```
match("^Word%-d[1-5]%-",string) 
match("%-Word%-d[1-5]%-",string)
```

Comment: `match("Word%-[1-5]%-%S+",string)` matches `Word-1-...` to `Word-5-...`, `match("Word%-1[1-5]%-%S+",string)` matches `Word-11-...` to `Word-15-...`

Comment: Are you matching the literal string `word` or are you using that as a stand-in? It would also help if you provided real world examples of strings you want to parse and what you want to get out of them. Also, string.match should be formatted `string.match(word, pattern)` (you have it as `string.match(pattern, word)`).

Answer (score 1):

Acording to you example, the idea could be something like this:

```html
<script src="https://github.com/fengari-lua/fengari-web/releases/download/v0.1.4/fengari-web.js"></script>
<script type="application/lua">

local text = [[
Word-1-random
Word-2-random
Word-3-random
Word-4-random
upto
Word-19-random

Other-Word-1-random
Other-Word-2-random
Other-Word-3-random
Other-Word-4-random
Other-Word-5-random
Other-Word-6-random
Other-Word-7-random
Other-Word-8-random
Other-Word-9-random
Other-Word-10-random
Other-Word-11-random
]]

local s1,s2
local grp,cnt = 0,0
text:gsub('(%S+%-)(%d+)(%-%S+)', function(p1,n,p2)
  if s1 ~= p1 or s2 ~= p2 or cnt == 5 then
    print('Group'..grp)
    s1,s2 = p1,p2
    cnt = 0
    grp = grp + 1
  end
  print(p1..n..p2)
  cnt = cnt + 1
end)

</script>
```